# Data is null. Trying to get the TIMESTAMPDIFF of 8AM and CurrentTime

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having the error "DATE IS NULL, THIS METHOD OR PROPERTY CANNOT BE CALLED ON NULL VALUES", I am trying to get the

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF( '08:00:00',CURTIME())
```

Here is my code,

```
if (timein <= 8)
    try {
        string query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'8:00',CURTIME()) AS 'madafa' FROM payroll.attendance WHERE Username='" + txtuser.Text + "' AND Date = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(source);
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //int name = reader.GetOrdinal("madafa");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //string namethestore = reader.IsDBNull(name)
              //                ? string.Empty
                //              : reader.GetString("madafa");
            minute = reader.GetInt32("madafa");
            label1.Text = minute.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

I dont know what data mysql is saying, I tried the code that I have made as a comment on my code above, which I saw here on stack overflow, but it didn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks! :D

Comment: Well where do you get the error, and what is the form of the error? I very much doubt that it's a *compile-time* error, so I suspect the compiler isn't involved at all. If it's an exception, please show the stack trace. Additionally, note that you should *immediately* stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL, every time.

Comment: ohh sorry for the confusion its not the compiler, its on mysql query, I guess its  in the TIMESTAMPFUNCTION, The error is Date is null. This method or property cannot be called on null value.

Comment: Again, please provide the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you look closely, you'll see he is passing in a bad timestamp to `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.  I'm fairly certain that `08:00:00` is not allowed, because it doesn't have a year or month, and how could MySQL possibly complete the function call?

Comment: its in here,
"minute = reader.GetInt32("madafa");"


"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Comment: @koorukairu: That's just the message, not a stack trace, and you *still* haven't put it in the question where it belongs, instead of comments.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I don't typically try to actually answer the question until the question itself is in a reasonable shape.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,                         -- time difference in minutes
                     CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 08:00:00'),  -- from 8am (add a space!)
                     CURTIME()) AS 'madafa'          -- until current time(stamp)
FROM payroll.attendance
WHERE Username='" + txtuser.Text + "' AND
      Date = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"
```

As @JonSkeet mentioned, your `WHERE` clause, as it currently stands, is prone to *SQL injection*, which is basically a security hole where malicious users can inject things into the query to retrieve information they should not be able to access, or can delete your data.

Comment: What output, if any, are you getting?  I'm pretty sure that the problem is your call to `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

Comment: theres no output though, I'm searching some alternatives to it, I guess the problem is in the 8am thingy, as that query works on the else estatement that I made, where has TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,TimeIN,CURTIME) and has no constant value/

Comment: Can you try running the raw query on MySQL directly?  This would at least rule out the query as being the problem (at least what you _intend_ the actual query to be).

Comment: Tim, it will return `NULL` because the second argument is not a `timestamp` (may be `NOW()` is preferred). Another important thing there should be a space before `08:00:00`. Please check [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/75402/0)

Comment: Sorry! the first line of my previous comment is wrong. Apology! But the second one is true. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @1000111 I added the space, good catch.  Yes, from what I saw, it is possible to feed a properly formatted string as a timestamp to `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, so I thought my answer made sense, at least when I wrote it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
Hello, Sorry I was asleep. Thank you so much your code worked! :D Thanks thanks :)

Thanks also 100111

Comment: please mark correct if it solved your problem thanks!